# correlation of two sums of random variables

Tags: self-study, correlation, covariance, random-variable

Imagine two random variables $X$ and $Y$ which are correlated with $\rho = 1$.

Both have a mean of $100$ and a standard deviation of $40$. Two other random variables $U$ and $V$ are correlated at $\rho=0.8$. Both have a mean of $0$ and standard deviation of $20$.

Now, I wonder if there is a formula to compute the correlation of $A = X+U$ and $B=Y+V$?

$\text{cor}(X,U)=\text{cor}(X,V)=\text{cor}(Y,U)=\text{cor}(Y,V)=0$

Any ideas on how to compute $\text{cor}(A,B)$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "cor(xu,xv,yu,yv)" mean?

Comment: Since this is routine book-work, please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag-wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), altering your question if necessary.

Comment: thanks, didn't know that. it means that cor(x,u) cor(x,v) and so on is zero

Comment: Just for a numerical check: the correlation between $A$ and $B$ is $0.92$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) write the correlation as a ratio (covariance is on the numerator, the denominator is a product of standard deviations)

2) Write covariance as an expectation and use elementary properties of expectation to compute $\text{cov}(X+U,Y+V)$.

3) Use elementary properties of variances to deal with the terms in the denominator

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties